# can coroutine be used to solve stack overflow due to too deep recursive function call?

Tags: recursion, heap-memory, stack-overflow, c++20, coroutine

Has anyone tried to use coroutine to solve stack overflow caused by too deep recursive function call? according to the document on coroutines, the coroutine state will be saved on heap instead of on stack, which could have the potential to avoid the limitation imposed by the limited stack size and thus provide a way to solve the stack overflow issue in a generic way. i have tried with some code but it looks like the stack over flow issue persists. anyone has any tips/advice to share? or point me to some tutorial? thanks in advance.

```cpp
// file main

#include "RecursiveCall.h"

// coroutine

static ReturnObject DoIntegration(Context& ctx, ReturnObject::promise_type* parent, double x_n)
{
    double* dummyA = new double[(int)((x_n + 1) * 2)]; // an effort to prevent heap allocation from "optimized out"

    co_await AwaitableBase(ctx, parent, x_n);

    ctx._dummyVec.push_back(dummyA); // part of the effort to prevent heap allocation from "optimized out"
}

// caller

static double Invoke(Context& ctx, ReturnObject::promise_type* parent, double x_n)
{
    auto ret = DoIntegration(ctx, parent, x_n);

    std::coroutine_handle<ReturnObject::promise_type> h = ret._coroH;
    auto p = h.promise();

    while (!h.done())
    {
        if (p.AreChildrenReady())
        {
            h(); 

            break;
        }
    }

    return p._area;
}

bool AwaitableBase::await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<PromiseType> h)
{
    _promise = &h.promise();

    if (_parent)
    {
        _parent->RegisterChild(h);
    }
        
    if (_x_n <= _ctx._b)
    {
        _promise->_x_n = 0.0;
        _promise->_area = 0.0;

        return false; 
    }

    _promise->_area = GetArea(_x_n, _ctx._incr);

    double newX = _x_n - _ctx._incr;

    _promise->_x_n = newX;

    double area = Invoke(_ctx, &h.promise(), newX);

    //post calculation
    _promise->_area += area;

    return true;
}

double CallRecursive(double x0, double x_n, double incr)
{
    Context ctx{ x0, incr };

    return Invoke(ctx, nullptr, x_n);
}

int main() 
{

    double x0 = 0.0;
    double x_n = 4.5;
    double incr = 0.5; // no stackoveflow
    //double incr = 0.0015; // stack oveflow

    auto area = CallRecursive(x0, x_n, incr);

    std::cout << "integrated result: " << area << "\n";
}
```

```cpp
// file RecrusiveCall.h

#include <coroutine>
#include <exception>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/* integration certainly can and should be done in a sequencial way in real world. but here is just use it as a simple example of recursive call, so the integration is implemented as a recursive function call and is done from high limit of x to the lower limit */

static double GetY(double x)
{
    using CurvePoint = std::pair<double, double>;
    constexpr CurvePoint curve[10] = { {0.0, 1.0}, {0.5, 1.2}, {1.0, 1.0}, {1.5, 1.2}, {2.0, 1.0},
                                       {2.5, 1.2}, {3.0, 1.0}, {3.5, 1.2}, {4.0, 1.0}, {4.5, 1.2} };

    if (x < curve[0].first || x > curve[9].first)
        return 0.0;

    CurvePoint newPoint;

    const auto p1 = std::lower_bound(&curve[0], &curve[10], x, [](const auto& a, const auto& b) constexpr { return a.first < b; });

    // check for special cases: first

    const auto p0 = p1 - 1;

    return (p1->second - p0->second) * (x - p0->first) / (p1->first - p0->first) + p0->second;
}

static double GetArea(double end, double incr)
{
    return (GetY(end) + GetY(end - incr)) * 0.5 * incr;
}

struct Context
{
    double _b; // lower limit of the integration range
    double _incr; // increment steplength

    std::vector<double*> _dummyVec; // effort to prevent heap allocation from being optimzed out

    ~Context()
    {
        for (auto p : _dummyVec)
            delete p;
    }
};

struct ReturnObject
{
    struct promise_type
    {
        using Handle = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

        ReturnObject get_return_object() {

            return  { std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this) };
        }

        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }

        void unhandled_exception() {}
        void return_void() {}

        void RegisterChild(Handle& childH)
        {
            _children.push_back(childH);
        }

        bool AreChildrenReady()
        {
            for (auto c : _children)
            {
                if (!c.done())
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        double GetValue() const { return _area; }

        std::vector<Handle>    _children;
        double _area{ 0 };
        double _x_n{ 0 };
    };
        
    ReturnObject(promise_type::Handle coro) : _coroH(coro)
    {

    }

    operator std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>() const { return _coroH; } 
    // A coroutine_handle<promise_type> converts to coroutine_handle<>
    operator std::coroutine_handle<>() const { return _coroH; }

    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> _coroH;
};

struct AwaitableBase
{
    typedef Context Ctx;
    using PromiseType = ReturnObject::promise_type; // todo: remove

    bool await_ready()
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<PromiseType> h);

    PromiseType* await_resume()
    {
        return _promise;
    }

    AwaitableBase(Ctx& ctx, PromiseType* parent, double x_n) : _ctx(ctx), _x_n(x_n), _parent(parent)
    {
    }

    ~AwaitableBase()
    {
    }

    Ctx& _ctx;
    PromiseType* _parent{ nullptr };
    PromiseType* _promise{ nullptr };
    double _x_n{ 0.0 };
};
```

Comment: "*solve stack overflow caused by too deep recursive function call?*" Have you tried... not doing that? You shouldn't *want* to recurse so deeply that you overflow the stack. Stacks are so large that the only code that's going to trigger them will either be broken (ie: infinite recursion) or just badly written (ie: code that shouldn't be recursive).

Comment: recursive function call is very useful in general because it often provides much more natural, intuitive implementation of algorithm/solution than any workaround.  in addition, stack over flow happens more often than people tend to expect for some applications, e.g. in computer aided engineering area, sometimes the animation frames are modeled as the depth/level of a tree and the number of frames could be easily as high as 50k!

Answer (score 0):

no.

the coroutine's stack frame remains allocated. what's pushed to heap (as custom handle struct) is minimal register state plus struct data, to later resume the stack frame.

that is how you can access all local variables after resuming where you left off.